# Android adding fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

**EDIT:**
In frag1 there is a `TextView`, when i click on it i navigate to frag2. There is an `EditText`and a button "Done". I enter some text there and press button "Done", when "Done" is pressed I save that text to data object and go back to frag1. When I'm back I update my `TextView` to show text from my dataobject, but `TextView` is not updated when using `add` method. When I use `replace` its all working prefectly, but I must use `add` for some reasons. Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Are you implying that you cannot view the change immediately or not able to view the change at all in the first screen ?

Comment: You should edit your question so it is more understandable. Right now, it is not clear what problem you are facing, making it difficult to provide meaningful answer.

Comment: I hope I explained it much better now...

Answer (score -1):

If its between 2 frags,  you can pass data to the intent and when you start the new intent ( frag in this case ) , retrieve the data back .

Hope this could help